# jquery animate div to move untill a child div is at a certain position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <div id="title_container"><h1 id="title">EXAMPLE<h1></div>
        <div id="slogan_container"><p id="slogan">EXAMPLE</p></div>
        <br/><br/>
        <nav id="menu_container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>nav1</li>
                <li>nav2</li>
                <li>nav3</li>
                <li>nav4</li>
                <li>nav5</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('header').animate({???},  5000, function(){
        window.location.href = link;
    });
});
```

So heres my problem:
I would like my entire "header" to move up until the "nav" is 5% from the top.
Anyone have an idea ?

Here im using -=60% to illustrate what i want to happen, but what i would want is the animation to stop when the "nav" reaches 5% from the top:
http://jsfiddle.net/6xPMW/

Comment: hey bro, i think you need to work with the height option within animate function. refer this for better understanding http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I guess this is not the perfect solution but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/6xPMW/3/

---

- Your `br`s look wrong, they should have the closing slash at the end,
  like so: `<br />`
- `<li>`s should not have an `href` attribute, rather put `<a>` tags
  inside or use the `rel` attribute for example: `<li rel="#">`
- I dont quite understand what shall happen. Your header shall be
  animated until what condition? Also, whats the point of doing the
  animation when you change the window.location anyways? Maybe you
  could provide a jsfiddle example, please.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the brs, for the li it was just a copying mistake on my part :)
i just added a jsfiddle